# sed: can't read /home/me/weather: No such file or directory

Tags: sed, conky

I have the following extract from a script that fetches weather information from accuweather:

```
wget -O ./weather_raw $address


if [[ -s ./weather_raw ]]; then

egrep 'Currently|Forecast<\/title>|_31x31.gif' ./weather_raw > ./weather
sed -i '/AccuWeather\|Currently in/d' ./weather
sed -i -e 's/^[ \t]*//g' -e 's/<title>\|<\/title>\|<description>\|<\/description>//g' ./weather
sed -i -e 's/&lt;img src="/\n/g' ./weather
sed -i '/^$/d' ./weather
sed -i -e 's/_31x31.*$//g' -e 's/^.*\/icons\///g' ./weather
sed -i -e '1s/.$//' -e '3s/.$//' -e '6s/.$//' ./weather
for (( i=2; i<=8; i+=3 ))
    do
        im=$(sed -n ${i}p ./weather)
        sed -i $i"s/^.*$/$(test_image $im)/" ./weather
    done

fi
```

The command that triggers the code above is in a conkyrc file and its `~/.conkyblue/accu_weather/rss/acc_rss`. When I run the conkyrc script from the prompt, I get an error

```
sed: can't read /home/me/weather: No such file or directory
```

And indeed when I check, the "weather" file is not created. However if run the command `~/.conkyblue/accu_weather/rss/acc_rss` directly from the prompt, it works as expected and create and puts content into the /home/me/weather file.

I don't know anything about the sed command although I'm trying to learn it as a result of this bother.

What could be the problem with the code. I don't think its a permission issue since the folder its writing into is my home folder and I of-course own it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should have been created by egrep.

When you run your script, the `weather` directory will be created in the `pwd` of the script process.

Check and see why egrep does not create the file, or in which directory it created it.

Comment: Thanks alinsoar, but I have checked and can't still figure out why its not creating the file. If it any help, I am using fedora 18

Comment: try to find the file with `find / -name weather`, probably you do not know the working directory of the script. If you know the working directory, check of it has set `+x` [writing access] flag for the user of the script.